# Issues with Plink

Tags: powershell

Here is my plink script. I am trying to add a config to a range of cisco switches, but it doesn't seem to be pushing through.

```
70..75 | % {plink "172.16.15.$_" -l myuser -pw mypass -m C:\location of config script}
```

This logs me into the switches but doesn't seem to apply the change. Here is my cisco script for the switches. I'm just trying to test it out by adding one vlan.

```
en
!
conf t
!
vlan 4
!
end
!
exit
```

I have saved this file both as a .txt file and also a .bat file. Does anyone notice anything I am doing wrong? Like I said I have no issues logging into the switch, its just getting plink to apply to change to the cisco config. I get logged into both switches, but it seems like the only thing it reads is the exit command out of the cisco config change I am trying to apply.

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious Does your script-file path contain spaces and have you therefore _quoted_ it? Do the commands in the script work interactively?

Comment: No spaces.path appears to be correct. Our switches have a log in banner,  I am seeing the login banner, so I am reaching the switch.after the log in banner it just goes back to the regular PS prompt. Then I manually putty into the switch to check and the change wasn't made.Is "-m" the correct command to point to my text file? I have seen people surround the file path with "< "and ">" also. Everything is working as far as connecting to the switch, just need to figure out how to execute the the text file that has the config change script.

Comment: Running `plink` without arguments shows the `-m` syntax as `-m file   read remote command(s) from file`, suggesting that no special syntax is required, and an nonexistent path seems to provoke an error. Are you confident that the commands in your script work as intended? Do they if you run them interactively?

Comment: Yes positive. If I take the "-m" and file path out, the switch script works fine, it takes me to the first ip in the range I put in, then the "exit" command takes me to the next switch in sequence. I am just trying to find a way to add a cisco script to the PS script so I can automate switch config changes. So I figured the way to do this would be point it to a text file containing the config change.

Comment: Could there be an encoding issue with the script file? Make sure it is encoded as ASCII / UTF-8 _without BOM_.

Comment: That's a little above my level, not ever sure what that means lol

Comment: Run `(Get-Content -Raw myConfigScript.txt) -replace "\`r\`n", "\`n" | Set-Content -NoNewLine -Encoding ASCII newConfigScript.txt` (PSv5+) and then pass `newConfigScript.txt` to `-m` instead. If that doesn't help, try to pass the contents of your script via the pipeline rather than via the `-m` option (`Get-Content myConfigScript.txt  | plink ...`)

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try then. I tried to do plink in cmd instead of PS and got the same issue.

Comment: So my script starts with a "conf t" because I am already in privilege exec mode when I log in. It went to do the command and all it typed what the "c" and then that was it, I was back to the PS prompt.

Comment: You used the transformed-to-ASCII-and-LF-only-newline file, with both methods?

Comment: Yeah I am getting the same thing. I see my login banner for the switch, but pretty much exits out of it and goes back to the regular PS prompt

Comment: Bummer. Unfortunately, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: (Get-Content mynewconfig.txt) | plink -ssh 172.16.15.4 -l username -pw password

Comment: Any issues you see with that? It is logging me into the switch, just not applying the config

Comment: You don't need the parentheses, but other than that I see no obvious problem - cannot test this myself, though.

Comment: Appreciate the help. I will keep digging and try and figure it out